# How to insert values from one table to another table?

Tags: mysql

I have authors table that contains author name and author_id(primary key). Another table called books has author name and author_id(foreign key) too. I have inserted values for author name in book table manually.
Now, I want to insert values in author id in book table by using the following query:

```
insert INTO tblbooks (Au_id) 
SELECT tblauthors.Au_id FROM tblauthors JOIN tblbooks ON 
tblbooks.a_name=tblauthors.AuthorName;
```

But i am getting an error :

## 1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Educated guess did you forgot adding the `AUTO_INCREMENT` option where the column has a `PRIMARY KEY` in the `tblbooks` table ? .. If that does not help or is not the case. i advice you to provide example data and expected results see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Duplicating the column `author_name` in the child table `books` is pointing out to a poor design. Please remove that column from that table. You already have a reference to `authors` table.

Comment: Thanks for your help  ....... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already have data in books table, you need to update author id instead of insert.

```
UPDATE tblbooks b
        INNER JOIN
    tblauthors a ON b.a_name = a.AuthorName 
SET 
    b.Au_id = a.Au_id;
```

Comment: You are making some pretty big assumptions here.